# Unable to select an object added using fabricjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'm adding an object into canvas using fabricjs. After adding that object, i an centring it's position using `obj.center()` method of fabricjs. That object is added to the center. Then i used `renderAll()` method.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    fill: 'red',
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    angle: 45
});

canvas.add(rect);
rect.center();
canvas.renderAll();
```

But there's one problem. I don't get the hover cursor(cursor with the hand) if i hover on that object. However, if i move my cursor to (0,0) coordinate position of the canvas, hover cursor is shown and clicking at that point selects that added object.

What am i dont wrong?

Comment: May be this will work Try to canvas.center() first and then canvas.add(rect)

Comment: After doing so, It doesn't even add the object.

Comment: rect.center();  canvas.add(rect);

canvas.renderAll();

Comment: It's not even adding the rectangle.

Comment: Found solution. `canvas.centerObject(rect); canvas.add(rect); canvas.renderAll(); `. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    fill: 'red',
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    angle: 45
});

canvas.add(rect);
rect.center();
rect.setCoords();
canvas.renderAll();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px dotted green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.16/fabric.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

after using [center()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#center) you need to call `setCoords()`.